# How do nested variable types change time complexity?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, time-complexity

I'm creating a list with nested types like this:

```
nested = [{}, set([]), []]
```

Assume each item in 'nested' has many items in it.

1. For each type of item in 'nested', what operations from [Python's Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) change complexity because the items are nested? For things like add, remove, pop, etc. If `nested[1]` and `nested[2]` each have 1,000 or 10,000 or 1,000,000 items, would performing operations on `nested[0]` change complexity for that dict?
2. What operations change complexity for the list 'nested'? For something like `nested.pop(2)` where `nested[2]` might have 1,000 items. Would `nested.pop(2)` take the same time if `nested[2]` had 1,000,000 items?

I'm concerned that adding nested items to a set, dict, and popping items in a list would change the O(1) advantage of those operations because of nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `nested[1]` and `nested[2]` have no effect whatsoever on the time taken to perform operations on `nested[0]`. An object has no knowledge of what containers it might be referenced in or what other objects might be in the container with it.
2. List operations take the same amount of time regardless of what objects are being added, removed, retrieved, or replaced. It doesn't matter what `nested[2]` is; `nested.pop(2)` takes the same amount of time. Hashing a large or highly nested tuple or other hashable object can take longer, so hash-based data structures like `dict` and `set` can take longer to work with large or highly nested keys, though there isn't any such concern with the values.